# Colors for drawing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, colors, draw

For my app, I need to implement a drawing space. With some help from an online tutorial I succeeded drawing. But the challenge now is to draw with different colors. I wrote the code beneath, but it doesn't work and I don't get it why it doesn't work. It paints just black.
I have the following in my UIView.m

```
    - (void)drawBitmap
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);

    if (!incrementalImage) // first time; paint background white
    {
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill];
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [color setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void)color1 {
    color = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (void)color2 {
    color = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

I call the functions from my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)drawGreen:(id)sender {
    SmoothedBIView *smoothView = [[SmoothedBIView alloc]init];
    [smoothView color1];
}

- (IBAction)drawYellow:(id)sender {
    SmoothedBIView *smoothView = [[SmoothedBIView alloc] init];
    [smoothView color2];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: The color is just black, it doesn't change to another color.

Comment: You have not shown how your functions color1 and color2 are being called.

Comment: Your question is clear as mud. What is "color" in the code `[color setStroke]`? Why are you both drawing incrementalImage into your context, and then fetching it as the output of your drawing?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that although you create a bitmap context you don't actually draw to it..
try this

```
    - (void)drawBitmap
    {

       CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);//changed

       UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);//changed

        if (!incrementalImage) // first time; paint background white
        {
            UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
            [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
            [rectpath fill];
        }
        [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [color setStroke];
        [path stroke];
        incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsPopContext(ctx); //changed

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

Comment: Initializing 'CGContextRef' (aka 'struct CGContext *') with an expression of incompatible type 'void', am I doing something wrong?